# How would I output the order total for each order ID (some are duplicate so would need a accumulated sum) using a cursor and loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, plsql, cursor

I am having trouble with figuring out how to add the sum of each order using the order ID if they are duplicates but still keeping the last record.

Order_original_total is a sum of every order in each row where the ID matches. Orders 1, 3, 5, and 6 have 2 orders each that make up each of their sums.

In the end, I made it so the if statement would check if the id in the row from the cursor matched the current id of the iteration.

It then adds to the order_original_total sum until it does not match. It then increments the current_order_id by 1.

The problem with that is it then goes past the last record and the last row isn't printed(row 6).

The way I have it, it skips the last entry.

which outputs this: [incorrect code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JreoG.png)
However, it should look like this: [correct code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YADK.png)

I currently have:

```
DECLARE

  original_total          NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
  order_original_total    NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
  discount_total          NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
  order_discount_total    NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
  difference              NUMBER(8,2) := 0;
  current_o_id            order_line.o_id%TYPE := 1;
  output_line             VARCHAR(200);

 CURSOR order_line_cursor IS
      SELECT order_line.o_id, inventory.inv_price, order_line.ol_quantity
      FROM order_line, inventory
      WHERE order_line.inv_id = inventory.inv_id;
      order_line_row   order_line_cursor%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('**** New Discount Results ****');
      OPEN order_line_cursor;

   LOOP
      FETCH
         order_line_cursor INTO order_line_row;
      EXIT WHEN order_line_cursor%NOTFOUND;

      original_total := original_total + (order_line_row.inv_price*order_line_row.ol_quantity);

    IF order_line_row.o_id = current_o_id THEN
        order_original_total := order_original_total + (order_line_row.inv_price*order_line_row.ol_quantity);
    ELSE 
        IF  order_original_total < 100 THEN
            order_discount_total := order_original_total;
            discount_total := discount_total + order_discount_total;
        ELSIF order_original_total > 100 AND order_original_total < 200 THEN
            order_discount_total := order_original_total - (order_original_total * .10);
            discount_total := discount_total + order_discount_total;
        ELSE
            order_discount_total := order_original_total - (order_original_total * .20);
            discount_total := discount_total + order_discount_total;
        END IF;

     output_line := 'Order #' || (order_line_row.o_id - 1) || ' Original Total: ' || TO_CHAR(order_original_total, '$999,999.99') || 
     TO_CHAR(order_discount_total, '$999,999.99');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(output_line);

    order_original_total :=  (order_line_row.inv_price*order_line_row.ol_quantity);
    current_o_id := current_o_id + 1;
    END IF;

    difference := original_total - discount_total;
   END LOOP;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL FOR ALL INVOICES: ');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Original Total: ' || TO_CHAR(original_total, '$999,999.99') || ' Discount Total: ' || discount_total || ' Difference: ' || TO_CHAR(difference, '$999,999.99'));
   CLOSE order_line_cursor;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get order 6 on your output because your control break logic is faulty. Your logic only out puts order details when the order number changes. So order 6 causes order 5 details to be output. However, since there is no order following number 6 it is never output as you have exited the loop before the break test. The solution for this is change to a cursor **FOR** loop instead of explicit cursor processing.  
You also have problem with calculating the discount. Order totals less than 100 get a 100% discount (your code: "order_discount_total := order_original_total"). Also orders of exactly 100 get a 20% discount (your code "order_original_total > 100 AND order_original_total < 200").  
Finally, there is no reason for any of this program logic - let SQL do it all the calculation and control breaking.

```
declare
   cursor order_line_cursor is
      select o_id
          , order_total, order_discount, order_total-order_discount order_net
          , total_ordered, total_discount, total_ordered-total_discount total_net
       from ( 
             select dis.*
                  , order_total - order_discount order_net
                  , sum(order_total) over()     total_ordered
                  , sum(order_discount) over()  total_discount
               from (  
                     select ord.*, round(case when order_total < 100 then 0
                                              when order_total < 200 then order_total * .10
                                              else order_total * .20
                                         end
                                       , 2) order_discount
                       from ( select order_line.o_id
                                   , round(sum( inventory.inv_price * order_line.ol_quantity),2) order_total
                                from order_line, inventory
                               where order_line.inv_id = inventory.inv_id 
                               group by order_line.o_id 
                            ) ord 
                    ) dis
            ) tot   
     order by o_id;

     l_total_ordered  number(8,2);
     l_total_discount number(8,2);
     l_total_net      number(8,2);

begin
      dbms_output.put_line('**** New Discount Results ****');

      for ol in order_line_cursor
      loop 
          dbms_output.put_line('order #' || ol.o_id || 
                               ' Original total: ' || to_char(ol.order_total, '$999,999.99') || 
                               ' Discount: ' || to_char(ol.order_discount,'$999,999.99') ||
                               ' Net Order: ' || to_char(ol.order_net,'$999,999.99')
                              );

          l_total_ordered  := ol.total_ordered ;
          l_total_discount := ol.total_discount;
          l_total_net      := ol.total_net;          
      end loop ;

       dbms_output.put_line('Total for All Invoices: ');
       dbms_output.put_line('Original total: '  || to_char(l_total_ordered, '$999,999.99') || 
                            ' Discount total: ' || to_char(l_total_discount, '$999,999.99') ||
                            ' Difference: '     || to_char(l_total_net, '$999,999.99'));

end;
```

Comment: Ohh okay. Thank you! I am new to cursors (learning now). This had me stumped. Appreciate the guidance.